# Auto Run a script every X minutes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script where it pulls data from a google sheet that imports a range from another sheet so when I update the sheet where the range is it updates in the google sheet that is connected to a dropdown in google forms. But I have to manually re run the script in the form to update what was updated in the sheet where the ranges are. Is there a way were the script would auto run itself to get the new information from the google sheet?

Comment: Have you tried using a trigger?

Comment: explain please...I am self teaching myself this I could show you my script if you would like

Answer (score 2):

You can install a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to execute a function with the frequency of your choice. The instructions are available [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

This is what the configuration looks like for running the function `update()` every 5 minutes.
[image]